# awk linux take difference and add tab delimited columns file

Tags: linux, unix, awk

I have a tab delimited file (no header) and I'd like to take the difference of column 3 and 2, and then add them all together.

Ie,

```
col1\tcol2\tcol3\tcol4
hi\t10\t100\t0.4
bye\t150\t400\t5.6
```

The result would be: (100-10)+(400-150)=340

How would I do such operation one-line using awk?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk '{ total += $3 - $2 } END { print total }' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="\t"} {sum+=($3-$2)} END{print sum}' input_file
```

**Explanation:**

- `BEGIN{FS="\t"}`: Before we read any lines, set input delimiter to use tabs explicitly  (`FS` stands for Field Separator), in case one of your fields has spaces. By default `awk` uses tabs and spaces as `FS`.
- `{sum+=($3-$2)}`: For each line read, add difference between 3rd to 2nd field to `sum`
- `END{print sum}`: Once all lines are read, print `sum`
- `input_file`: Specify input file name to `awk` as an argument; save a cat.